# ParcelFileDescriptor throwing File Not Found Exception

Tags: android

Why is Parcel File Descriptor throwing FileNotFounException even if the imageUri is not null or empty. I have selected a file from my gallery using Intent. I also toast the value of "imageUri", it prints.

```
      ParcelFileDescriptor percelFileDescriptor;
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+imageUri.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      try {
           percelFileDescriptor = getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(imageUri, "r");
           image = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(percelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor());
           modified_img_bitmap = image;
           percelFileDescriptor.close();
           picked_image.setImageBitmap(image);
           } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
           System.out.println("File Not Found: " + e.toString());
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"File not found: "+e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           } catch (IOException e) {
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"IO Error: "+e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           System.out.println("IO Exception: " + e.toString());
           }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and that works. Please, post your full code.

That works:

```
private final int GALLERY_REQUEST = 0;
Uri imageUri;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent pictureActionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

    startActivityForResult(pictureActionIntent, GALLERY_REQUEST);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
    {
        switch (requestCode)
        {
            case GALLERY_REQUEST:

                if (data != null)
                {
                    imageUri = data.getData();

                    Bitmap image = null;
                    Bitmap modified_img_bitmap = null;
                    ImageView picked_image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                    ParcelFileDescriptor percelFileDescriptor;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+imageUri.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    try
                    {
                        percelFileDescriptor = getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(imageUri, "r");
                        image = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(percelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor());
                        modified_img_bitmap = image;
                        percelFileDescriptor.close();
                        picked_image.setImageBitmap(image);
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e)
                    {
                        System.out.println("File Not Found: " + e.toString());
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"File not found: "+e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"IO Error: "+e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        System.out.println("IO Exception: " + e.toString());
                    }
                }

                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```